# A container for Strings^

Tags: types, managed-c++

I have this variable:

```
array<String^> ^strings;
```

I want to iterate over it with a `for each` loop and add some of the elements to another container. What data type should I use? Both vector and list don't seem to work with managed types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the .NET `List<T>`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx